# Unable to connect, incorrect logon parameters

Tags: authentication, parameters, crystal-reports, adodb

Following code works fine on local system but on remote server this error  is given:

> Logon failed.
>   Details: ADO
>   Error Code: 0x
>   Source: ADODB.Connection
>   Description: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.
>   Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\MARK_F_CARD {F5EE7A57-7C81-4AC5-B39E-E3E66C864F4B}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect logon on parameters.

Can anyone suggest any solution?

```
cl.ConOpen();
DataSet dsm = new DataSet();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

string query_report1 = "select *from ZSTUDENT where SID='" + Wsid.Text + "'";
cl.da = new SqlDataAdapter(query_report1, cl.con);
cl.da.Fill(dsm, "ZSTUDENT");

rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("../MARKSHEETDESIGN/MARK_F_CARD.rpt"));
rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("sms", "sms", "204.0.0.237", "sms");
rpt.SetDataSource(dsm);

string query_report2 = "select *from STUDENTMARK where SID='" + Wsid.Text + "'";
cl.da = new SqlDataAdapter(query_report2, cl.con);
cl.da.Fill(ds, "STUDENTMARK");

rpt.Subreports[0].SetDatabaseLogon("sms", "sms", "204.0.0.237", "sms");
rpt.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(ds);
//-------
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo { UserID = "sms", Password = sms", ServerName = "204.0.0.237", DatabaseName = "sms" };
TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo { ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo };
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in rpt.Database.Tables) {
    table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
}
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in rpt.Subreports[0].Database.Tables) {
    table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
}
//-----
rpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;
CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```